# Incorrect in getting the date of every Thursday of current month in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dayofweek

I tried to find out the Thursday of every week. It giving the right output if the current day is less than Thursday. And it gives wrong output if we are on Friday & Saturday.

```
 Private Function GetNextDate(day As DayOfWeek) As DateTime

        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Today
        Dim today As Integer = CInt(now.DayOfWeek)
        Dim find As Integer = CInt(day)

        Dim delta As Integer = find - today

        If delta > 0 Then
            Return now.AddDays(delta)

        Else
            Return now.AddDays(7 - delta)
        End If
    End Function

' For output
 Dim comingThursday = GetNextDate(DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        MsgBox(comingThursday.ToString)
```

Please help me out to find out the coming Thursday date properly. Or suggest me any other better way to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Your `delta` variable will be negative when the day you request (Thursday) is before the current day (Friday or Saturday) of the week. You therefore have to **add** it to 7, not subtract it:

```
now.AddDays(7 + delta)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir...it working fine. Is there any way to identify the last Thursday of the month along with above code ?.

Comment: For that you'd be better off using djv's code.

Comment: Thank you sir for your great support...Thanks once again for the help.

Comment: @tasklive please mark one of the answers as accepted so your question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Without worrying about the math, you can use LINQ to query the days in the current month, and filter on the day of the week you want

```vb
Private Function getDaysOfWeekInCurrentMonth(dayOfWeek As DayOfWeek) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
    Return Enumerable.
        Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Now.Year, Now.Month)).
        Select(Function(i) New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, i)).
        Where(Function(d) d.DayOfWeek = dayOfWeek)
End Function
```

```vb
Dim thursdays = getDaysOfWeekInCurrentMonth(DayOfWeek.Thursday)
For Each thursday In thursdays
    Debug.WriteLine(thursday)
Next
```

> 7/6/2023 12:00:00 AM
>
> 7/13/2023 12:00:00 AM
>
> 7/20/2023 12:00:00 AM
>
> 7/27/2023 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir...it working fine. Is there any way to identify the last Thursday of the month along with above code ?.

Comment: `Dim lastThursday As DateTime = getDaysOfWeekInCurrentMonth(DayOfWeek.Thursday).Last`

Comment: Thank you sir...you helped me a lot........Really appreciating your support.....Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Some code that might help

```
''' <summary>
''' returns the date of the next DayOfWeek
''' </summary>
''' <param name="whDay">which DayOfWeek</param>
''' <param name="BasedOn">based on this date the next DayOfWeek</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function GetNextDOW(whDay As DayOfWeek,
                                BasedOn As Date) As Date
    Dim delta As Integer = whDay - BasedOn.DayOfWeek
    'depending on definition the comparison might just be .GT.
    ' as written if it is Wed and we are looking for the next Wed
    '  then skip ahead one week
    If BasedOn.DayOfWeek >= whDay Then
        delta += 7
    End If
    Dim rv As Date = BasedOn.AddDays(delta)
    ' Debug.WriteLine("The next {0} is {1} based on {2}", whDay, rv.ToShortDateString, BasedOn.ToShortDateString)
    Return rv
End Function
```

To test:

```
    Debug.WriteLine("")
    Dim dt As Date = #7/1/2023#
    Dim d As Date
    Do
        'all Monday's in July
        d = GetNextDOW(DayOfWeek.Monday, dt)
        If d.Month = dt.Month Then
            Debug.WriteLine("The next {0} is {1} based on {2}",
                                DayOfWeek.Monday, d.ToShortDateString, dt.ToShortDateString)
        End If
        dt = d
    Loop While dt.Month = 7

    Debug.WriteLine("")
    'first Thursday
    dt = #7/1/2023#
    If dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Thursday Then 'see comment in GetNextDOW
        d = GetNextDOW(DayOfWeek.Thursday, dt)
    End If

    'last Thursday
    dt = New Date(2023, 7, 31)
    If dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Thursday Then 'see comment in GetNextDOW
        dt = dt.AddDays(-7)
        d = GetNextDOW(DayOfWeek.Thursday, dt)
    End If
```